# AS3: How to get fullscreen and keyboard input?

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard, fullscreen

Since flash doesn't allow keyboard input while in fullscreen mode I'm wondering if there is a workaround to that?

I have a flash that is going to run fullscreen in a browser and needs different kinds of keyboard input. I have read something about AIR, but I don't fully understand it and would like another way if thats even possible.

Anybody knows?

Comment: You could take a look at Silverlight. As far as I remember Silverlight 4 (currently in beta) will allow a user to "trust" a silverlight application so the keyboard can be used in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Hahaha, Silverlight.

Answer (score 6):

```
public function setFullScreen():void
            {
                this.width = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
                this.height = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
                this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
                this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;

            }
```

Use the `FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE`

Comment: [`FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageDisplayState.html#FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE) is only for flash player >= 11.3 (and AIR 1.0).

Comment: Helpful!  See docs [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageDisplayState.html#FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE)

Comment: This doesn't cause the flash movie to become full screen, only to resize and thus not fit the browser window

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible in Flash Player 11.3+

Simply compile your application to support a minimum version of 11.3.0 and it will work if you use:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

in your html you must put:

```
<param name="allowFullScreenInteractive" value="true" />
```

you will see a prompt when you enter full screen:

[image: Permission Overlay]

you can see an example on this official adobe blog:
http://www.leebrimelow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/overlay.gif

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get input key with fullscreen mode within the browser.

Air is only for desktop application so if your application have to work into the browser no Air for you.

If you have to get input into fullscreen mode you can try to make a virtual keyboard ([an example](http://activeden.net/item/on-screen-virtual-keyboard-as-30/55005)) and user will use the mouse to press the keyboard key.

Answer (score 2):

It actually is possible in Flash 10, but only for a few keys. See this page: 
[Understanding the security changes in Flash Player 10](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes_03.html#head5)

> Flash Player 9 does not allow keyboard
>   input when displaying content in
>   full-screen mode. Flash Player 10
>   changes this, allowing for a limited
>   number of keys to be usable in
>   full-screen mode. These include Tab,
>   the Spacebar, and the (up, down, left,
>   right) arrow keys.

Comment: Yeah, I know. A bit better, but still not helping when I want p for pause/play and s for sound on/off ;)

Thanks anyway =)

Comment: -1 - Your answer is outdated. Flash Player 11.3 allows full textfield editing capabilities in Fullscreen, which can be activated with the command : `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just use the browser's built-in fullscreen capability. All major browsers offer it as far as I know (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc). Usually it's under View->Fullscreen, hotkey F11. Depending on the browser it will either give you the entire screen, or maybe leave a small bar across the top/bottom. Then you simply need to make your flash application expand to fill the entire HTML page.

Comment: Yes, that's an option but not a very good one. Unless.. Can I maybe make the browser do that with code? That would be great! Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0):

Patrick is right. Due to security risks, your going to have a tough time getting your goal met. Adobe AIR is your best solution and will be easy to achieve in your state.

Here is a great video to get your started from Lee Brimelow. http://theflashblog.com/?p=403 (Building AIR Applications in Flash CS3)

Since AIR applications are built right in Flash or Flex, all you will need to do is configure how your application compiles, and you have yourself a Adobe AIR application capable of utilizing the keyboard while running as a cross platform desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, AIR is not for browsers? Too bad. Seems like I won't be able to get everything I wish for :p I have functions for the most important things without the keyboard functions, but I would really like them all of course.

I'll look into Silverlight then and see if thats an option.

Thanks guys! :)