# AS3 No keyboard response (except for Space button) and can't type into input TextFields while in HTML

Tags: actionscript-3, input, keyboard, textfield

I have no problem with my app when I run it ctrl+enter or when I only open the .swf file, but once I open the HTML file and go into fullscreen mode, for some reason, I can't type into the text fields that are input any more. What's weirdest is that while the Space key still works, the Shift key doesn't.

Here's some code parts:

```
stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fullScreen);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keys);
...
function keys(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
switch(e.keyCode){
    case Keyboard.SHIFT:
        popup.popupText.text=popupResult();
        popup.visible=!popup.visible;
    break;
    case Keyboard.SPACE:
        switch(stav){
            case 0:
                stav=1;
                var date:Date=new Date();
                startTime=date.getTime();
                zarovkaA.play();
                horakB.play();
                timer.start();
            break;
            case 2:
                stav=3;

                counter.visible=false;
                leftIn.visible=false;
                rightIn.visible=false;
                inBg.visible=false;

                leftOut.visible=true;
                rightOut.visible=true;
                centropol.visible=true;

                leftOut.text=getResult(leftIn.text);
                rightOut.text=getResult(rightIn.text);

                centropol.text="s CENTROPOL ENERGY\njsi na svícení ušetřil\n";
                            /*+(calToKc(parseInt(leftIn.text))+
                              calToKc(parseInt(rightIn.text)))
                            +" Kč/rok";*/
                calSum+=parseInt(leftIn.text)+parseInt(rightIn.text);
            break;
            case 3:
                stav=0;
                counter.visible=true;
                counter.text=format(maxTime);

                inBg.visible=false;

                leftIn.visible=false;
                rightIn.visible=false;
                leftOut.visible=false;
                rightOut.visible=false;

                rightIn.text="";
                leftIn.text="";

                centropol.visible=false;
            break;
        }
    break;
}
}
...
function fullScreen(e:MouseEvent):void{
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3: How to get fullscreen and keyboard input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409721/as3-how-to-get-fullscreen-and-keyboard-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use instead of StageDisplayState.FULLSCREEN, StageDisplayState.FULLSCREEN_INTERACTIVE which will give you a popup to allow or not typing in the swf, which is something the user allows or not.

Note this works only with Flash Player 11.1 or above. Or was it 11.3? Anyway always compile in last or next to last flash player (for security, performance and stability).

Comment: well I tried using FULLSCREEN_INTERACTIVE and nothing happened, using flash CS5.5, although I havent updated my flash player for a couple months... anyway, I resolved it by simply putting the browser into fullscreen mode instead of the flash movie. This works fine for my purpose